# Creating files through mounted Samba share makes them executable by user

Tags: permissions, samba

I created a Samba share on my Ubuntu virtual machine and mounted the share on my Windows 7 host using `net use W: \\blog.localhost\blog`.  When editing or creating any file it sets the perms to `-rwxr--r--`, and it should be setting it to `-rw-r--r--`.  I need it to not set the file to executable for the user.  Below is my configuration for the share.

```
[blog]
comment = Development files for Wordpress Blog.
browseable = yes
writable = yes
path = /var/www/wordpress
create mask = 0644
force create mode = 0644
valid users = lpeabody
inherit permissions = yes
force user = lpeabody
force group = www-data
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by removing `inherit permissions` and restarting Samba.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote.  It's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Samba maps the windows `system` and `archive` bits to `group` and `user` execute. I believe this is done AFTER creation; so the *create mask* and *create mode* settings wouldn't help.

Look into the 'map archive', 'map system', and 'map hidden' settings.

Comment: Sorry I already figured it out... thanks though.  I was honestly racking my brain for over an hour, but I guess I just needed to walk away for a while.

Answer (score 0):

For other users with the same problem:

Ensure that you have masks set; if they're missing, they'll often default to include +x.  Example:

```
[share]
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

You'll also need to omit `inherit permissions`, or set it to `no`.